# Combine and sum the values in multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

All the relevant code is provided here http://jsfiddle.net/DuWGj/ , as well as print(appendTo) statements.

To keep it short, I'm making 4 arrays. Each array has 4 numbers. Then I create a new array that has all those 4 arrays numbers inside of it, so it's one array.

For example the end result is

```
four.myArraysCombined = [5,3,20,12,3,4,18,11,12,5,8,2,1,9,10,6];
```

However, when I try

`four.myArraysCombined[3]`  , it says it's undefined.

so obviously when I do the following it doesn't work

```
var total = 0;
for (var x = 0; x < 16; x++) {
    total += four.myArraysCombined[x]);
}
```

I'm looking to be able to add all those numbers together with a for loop. I've tried several things but it keeps giving me undefined or NaN.

Comment: have you done a `console.log(four.myArraysCombined)` to see if you really are generating the array you think you have?

Comment: You can generate your combined array as simple as: `myArrays.join().split(",").map(function(entry) { return Number(entry) })`

Comment: uhm... i dont' know if is the error... but you push your temp array inside other empty array... try to use `=` instead `push()` i edit your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DuWGj/1/ - follow the comment in JS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### What is happening

After running:

```
prePickNumbers(four, 4, 40, 20, 1);
```

...the value of `four.myArraysCombined` is:

```
[[[2, 17, 20, 1], [7, 2, 20, 11], [7, 14, 3, 16], [12, 17, 3, 8]]]
```

In other words, it is not the result that you claim it is. You should verify that you have the result that you think you do *at each step* of the process, before moving on. As it stands, you do not have a flattened array. You need to fix that first and then move on to iterating and summing.

### Why this is happening

The reason for the final structure starts at the following line in `prePickNumbers`:

```
tempMyArraysCombined.push(objName.myArray[x]);
```

You're pushing an *array* into another array each time, so the result after the loop is an array of arrays. But, then, you push *that* result into another array:

```
objName.myArraysCombined.push(tempMyArraysCombined);
```

So the final result is actually an array containing an array of arrays (notice the extra set of brackets in the output above). The problem is that you're pushing an entire array into your output at each step in the process, which is creating a nested mess. You should be pushing *elements* of each array, not the arrays themselves.

### How to fix it

Here is one possible solution. Replace `prePickNumbers` with the following function:

```
function prePickNumbers(objName, theNum, theSumNum, theMaxNum, theMinNum) {
    var tempMyArraysCombined = [];
    for (var x = 0; x < theNum; x += 1) {
        pickNumbers(objName.myArray[x], theNum, theSumNum, theMaxNum, theMinNum);
        for (var j = 0; j < objName.myArray[x].length; j++) {
            objName.myArraysCombined.push(objName.myArray[x][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the value shown here is an array with one item, that one item is an array with 4 items. notice the three opening square brackets. [[[

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try

```
 total += four.myArraysCombined[0][x]
```

Answer (score 1):

I extract this from you fiddle:

```
function prePickNumbers(objName, theNum, theSumNum, theMaxNum, theMinNum) {
    var tempMyArraysCombined = [];
    for (var x = 0; x < theNum; x += 1) {
    pickNumbers(objName.myArray[x], theNum, theSumNum, theMaxNum, theMinNum);
    tempMyArraysCombined.push(objName.myArray[x]);
    }
    objName.myArraysCombined.push(tempMyArraysCombined); 
}
```

edit the last line to:

```
function prePickNumbers(objName, theNum, theSumNum, theMaxNum, theMinNum) {
    /* your code */
    objName.myArraysCombined=tempMyArraysCombined; //edit this line not push() but =
}
```

now there are no "UNDEFINED" in output html.
:)